# Block ALT key globally in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm trying to block the ALT from being used in all Input fields for my Angular app.  Here is what I have tried.

In the app.component adding the following:

```
@HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
public handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    const keycode = event.key;

    if (event.altKey ||
        keycode.toLowerCase() == 'alt' ||
        event.altKey === true ||
        event.code == Constants.KeyCodes.AltRight ||
        event.code == Constants.KeyCodes.AltLeft) {
        event.returnValue = false;
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
}
```

This code fires properly, however it does not prevent the Alt key combination from stopping.  For instance press Alt + 5 and you get ♣.  The strange thing is that if I add a breakpoint and step through the code it works, so it's like some weird timing issue.

I took the same code and added it to a service and called it from the app.component like the following:

```
fromEvent(document, 'keyup').subscribe((event: KeyboardEvent) => {
        this.utilityService.altKeyBlocking(event);
})

fromEvent(document, 'keydown').subscribe((event: KeyboardEvent) => {
        this.utilityService.altKeyBlocking(event);
})
```

The only thing that seems to work is creating a Directive and adding it to every Input field in the entire application using the exact same code.

Thoughts on other things I can try to implement this globally.  Peace.

Comment: You might be capturing `Alt`, but my guess is that combinations of keys trigger a different keyboard event. Have you checked if `Alt + 5` triggers a separate event?

Comment: could you reproduce it on a stackblitz? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-egdqld?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Is stopping ALT from being pressed the problem, or the solution. Is the problem bad characters are being input from using alt or is it that only alt + ‘some key’ is prohibited? It seems odd to only want to ban alt key combinations and not other chars as well. Making a whitelist directive seems cleaner and more complete, but I don’t know if that’s what you actually need.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez yes it is causing a 2nd trigger, however the event.altKey is still true.  Somehow the propegation of the key stroke doesn't stop.  See this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v5e8zq

Comment: @eko yes it is reproduced here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v5e8zq  Not that if you do Alt + 5 that character still displays in the input field.  I thought the event.preventDefault and returnValue would stop that from writing out the character.

Comment: @bjlasc01 since the project has already started I was looking for a more global solution instead of going into each component and adding the directive.  Currently only a directive works, but I'm not sure why.  If you look here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v5e8zq and press Alt + 5 the ♣ is still written in the input field.  I want to prevent invalid characters from being entered with the Alt + [any key], from there I will add additional whitelist characters.